# Why are my lists not rendering in PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I'm making a small RSS reader and I want it to parse a website and make a list of the feed. But the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags aren't being rendered. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");

function jobs() {
    $output = array();
    $feed_url = 'http://www.jobs.ge/rss/jobs/';
    $feed = simplexml_load_file($feed_url);

    for($j=0; $j<10; $j++){

        $title = $feed ->channel->item[$j]->title;
        $link = $feed ->channel->item[$j]->link;
        $desc= $feed ->channel->item[$j]->description;
        $date = $feed ->channel->item[$j]->pubDate;

        $output[] = array (
            'title' =>$title,
            'link' =>$link,
            'description'=> $desc,
            'date'=> $date,
        );
    }
    return $output;
}

$feed = jobs();
?>

<ul>
<?php
    foreach ($feed as $item) {
        echo '<li>', $item['title'],'</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You said it doesn't work. What happens?

Comment: It doesn't render correctly. Just like this:
<ul>
<li>შიდა აუდიტორი</li> ........some stuff here...... </ul>

Comment: never mind these symbols: "შიდა აუდიტორი" They're on my language :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the content-type to `text/plain` so the browser does what it should and renders it as plain text. Set the content-type to `text/html` and it should render even though it's not completely valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here. Output is:

```
<ul>
<li>შიდა აუდიტორი</li><li>დისტრიბუტორი/სტაჟიორი</li><li>პროექტების მენეჯერის ასისტენტი</li><li>შეფ-მზარეულის ასისტენტი</li><li>აღმრიცხველ-ოპერატორი</li><li>პრისელერი, სტაჟიორი</li><li>გაყიდვების აგენტი</li><li>სხვადასხვა</li><li>პროექტის მენეჯერი</li><li>მრეწველობის ინჟინერი</li></ul>
```